# How to programmatically force EGORefreshTableHeaderView to update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, refresh

I am trying to force `EGORefreshTableHeaderView` to update from the code. When I pull down everything works perfect and the `TableView` (root) gets refreshed. But I have a modal view where the user can subscribe to certain entities. When he subscribes to one the reload method in the first (root) table view gets triggered. This method establishes a connection to a server, loads some specific data based on the subscription, stores it in a `CoreData DB` and updates the `TableView` (root).

The problem is that when the user is only connected to 3G or Edge network the download, which is processed in an own thread, can take several seconds. To indicate the user that something happens I would like to show the `EGORefreshTableHeaderView`.

I found out that I can set the indent of the refresh view and manually show the loading icon but I was wondering if there is not an easier solution by just triggering a delegate or a method on the `EGORefreshTableHeaderView`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try using `egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceStartManualLoading`?

Assuming your `EGORefreshTableHeaderView` instance is named _refreshTableHeaderView, then a call like:

```
[_refreshTableHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceStartManualLoading:self.tableView];
```

works for me...

---

So, it's been too long since I used this, and I forgot I applied the change myself...

I modified `EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate` (declared in `EGORefreshTableHeaderView.h`) to add this additional protocol:

```
- (void)egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceStartManualLoading:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

And the implementation (in `EGORefreshTableHeaderView.m`):

```
- (void)egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceStartManualLoading:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self setState:EGOOPullRefreshLoading];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:)]) {
        [_delegate egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:self];
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more help there.

(And thank-you **enormego** for the great work!)

Comment: According to [1] there is no method like you have mentioned above? Maybe you have implemented this on your own? Could you share me the code please?
[1] ... https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Comment: Thank you. I have also tried this in a similar way but yours works better. Additionally, I have rewritten the animation to block animations because of commitAnimations is deprecated since iOS5 I guess. But anyway: Thank you! :)

Comment: Mh... I found out that it does not work when the TableView consists of more cells as its height. Then the RefreshView is triggered but not shown due the user have to scroll UP to see it. Do you have any suggestions? :/

Comment: I have found it out. See ma answer below if someone needs this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Reuven and his code I have improved it a little bit that it can also be used in an UIScrollView that is larger as the screen. Additionally, I have changed the deprecated `commitAnimations` to block animations.

```
#pragma mark - Manually refresh view update
- (void)egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceStartManualLoading:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self.refreshHeaderView setState:EGOOPullRefreshLoading];

    //animating pull down scroll view
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{ 
                         scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
                         scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -60.0f);
                     }
     ];

    //triggering refreshview regular refresh
    if ([self.tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:)]) {
        [self egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:self.refreshHeaderView];
    }
}
```